# C# How Can i Get Column Name From Database with its value

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlite

I would like to get column name from database with it is value

```
|Field1 |Field2 |Field3 |Field4 |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
| 1     | 0     | 0     | 1     |
```

i would like to get ones as an example. But i dont know how to do it. I would like to use this query in  c#. And also i dont know how to print the result out. I need help about that either. If somebody could help me i would be really appriciated. I am using sqlite.

Comment: you would have to test each column separately and return whether each column matches - either as separate columns, or as a manually constructed bitmask. There's no inbuilt "tell me which columns have this value" feature in most RDBMS AFAIK

Comment: but how will i get name of column and print it out

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do.  You say you want to "get ones as an example."  Are you trying to return all records where Field1, Field2, Field3, or Field4 is 1?  Or are you trying to figure out, for a given record, which fields are 1?

Comment: _"I would like to use this query in c#"_ - where is your query? Also what is the purpose of doing that, if you will explain your ideas, maybe we can suggest different ways.

Comment: If you can post your code so far, what you're expecting it to do, and what it's actually doing, that will go a long way.

Comment: If i would have query i wouldnt write here in the begining. I was trying to be as a clear as possible. I have table the shown figure rest of table i would like to get field1 and field4 obviosly when i meant **get ones as an example**. There is nothing to post about code everything is okey i just need one query to add and get this result

Comment: Couldn't you just do a `Select *` to get all the fields?  Also are you using ADO.Net or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get field name please try

```
using(IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteQuery())
{
    reader.Read();
    var field = reader.GetName(0);
    var value = reader.GetValue(0);
}
```

Comment: but how can i get how many columns, it works well but i need to write column number manually

Answer (score 0):

You can get the names of the columns in your table using 
"`PRAGMA table_info(your_table_name);`" and then build a dynamic query by iterating over those names.